# Viewer does not show pdf file

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to show a pdf file in a viewer of sort to show the contents of the pdf. however the viewer outputs blank.

the file is located (uploaded) via a folder named 'pdf'

this is my href code to pass which pdf should be shown

```
<a href="viewimage.php?docnamepath='<?php echo $scannedfilepath; ?>'" class="btn btn btn-success btn-sm"  
                                        name="btnview"
                                        id="btnview"><i class="fa-solid fa-thin fa-envelope fa-xs;"></i> View PDF </a>
```

this is what it looks like in the url

```
http://localhost/recordsmanagement/viewimage.php?docnamepath='pdf/FAQs on RA11210 and the IRR.pdf'
```

this is how I read the pdf

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

if(!isset($_GET['docnamepath'])) {
  $docnamepath=$_GET['docnamepath'];
}



if(isset($_GET['docnamepath'])){

  /** separate name and dir */
  $str_arr = explode ("/",$_GET['docnamepath']);

  $content = $str_arr[0];
  $dir = "pdf/";



// Store the file name into variable
$file = $dir . $content;
$filename = $content;



// Header content type
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

// Read the file
@readfile($file);

}

?>
```

the output looks like this. It is blank, what could be causing this

[image]

I got the idea by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404686/show-pdf-file-content-as-a-viewer) example

I have already tried attaching the file in an email via php
the pdf seems fine when sent via email so why is my pdf viewer not showing the pdf

**UPDATE:**

I have looked into @KD's comment and tried to use a file with no spaces

[image: no spaces]

still does not work on my end

Comment: @KJ is href best practice for this setup. sorry about the localhost it is still under development

Comment: @KJ I used urlencode and spaces converted to + and / converted to %2f

Comment: @KJ thank you I have checked the link and tried basename() function. it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [KJ's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j) comment I checked this link [which is about how to get filename to get full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-do-i-get-a-file-name-from-a-full-path-with-php)

and I recently discovered (I am a beginner in php) about the `basename function`

as shown in the answers in the link

```
$filename = basename($path);
```

instead of using this:

```
/** separate name and dir */
$str_arr = explode ("/",$_GET['docnamepath']);

$content = $str_arr[0];
$dir = "pdf/";
  
// Store the file name into variable
$file = $dir . $content;
$filename =  $content;
```

I changed the code to this:

```
// Store the file name into variable
$file = $_GET['docnamepath'];
$filename =  basename($path);
```

it shortened my code and now my pdf viewer is working.